# jScrollPane not working, but no errors displayed

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'ved added jScrollPane on the following page for the tradeshow area: http://mmicet.yazminmedia.com. However, I seem to have done something wrong and the script isn't working for me.

This is what I have in my head area:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
$(function() {
    $('.scroll-pane-before').jScrollPane(
        {
            showArrows: true,
            arrowScrollOnHover: true,
            verticalArrowPositions: 'before',
            horizontalArrowPositions: 'before'
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

And this is where the script is being used:

```
<p class="tradeshow scroll-pane-before">
tradeshow infotradeshow infotradeshow info
tradeshow infotradeshow infotradeshow info
tradeshow infotradeshow infotradeshow info
tradeshow infotradeshow infotradeshow</p>
```

When I inspect my code, I'm not seeing any errors.

Anyone have any ideas what may be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out jScrollPane doesn't play well with another class attribute specified along side it. Once I modified the code to:

```
<p class="scroll-pane-before">
```

It started working.